# Removing many Exchange full access permissions on a mailbox

Tags: exchange, scripting, powershell

I'm trying to use Powershell to remove certain full access permissions on an account as part of a disable user process.

I need to remove all full access permissions on the account except for:

`NT AUTHORITY\SELF`
and
`DOMAIN\svcEnterpriseVault`

How can I go about doing this using the `Remove-MailboxPermission` cmdlet?

Thanks

Edit:
I've gotten a little further with the command below, but I am having trouble passing the list of full-access users to the Remove-MailboxPermission cmdlet.

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $TheUser | Select User | where {($_.User -notlike
 "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\svcEnterpriseVault")} | Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity $TheUser -User [ALL THE USERS FROM THE GET-MAILBOX COMMAND]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just do this?  I removed the "Select User" since that is for display purposes only and used no parameters on "Remove-MailboxPermision" since it accepts input.  Haven't tested though.

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $TheUser | where {($_.User -notlike
"NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\svcEnterpriseVault")} | 
Remove-MailboxPermission
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to this site I tried to add `-Identity` at the end of the line, as in the line on the top. This worked for me.

I excluded also some other users, because I don't know exactly what they do, am afraid to delete too much. I also added `-confirm:$false`:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $TheUser | where {($_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and ($_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Exchange Servers") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Exchange Trusted Subsystem") -and ($_.User -notlike "S-1-5-21*") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Domain Admins") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Organization Management") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Enterprise Admins") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Administrator") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Public Folder Management") -and ($_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service") -and ($_.User -notlike "DOMAIN\Delegated Setup")} | Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity $TheUser -AccessRights FullAccess -confirm:$False
```